# Pandas, Memory error when trying to substract two arrays

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'd been working with a large dataset with shape (345602,12) doing all sorts of analysis with scikitlearn. I had no problems until I ran the RandomForestRegressor:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                    test_size=0.4,
                                                    random_state=1)

forest = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,
                               criterion='mse',
                               random_state=1,
                                n_jobs=-1)

forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_train_pred = forest.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = forest.predict(X_test)
```

This part works, resulting in:

```py
print(y_train.shape, y_train_pred.shape)
(207361,1) (207361,)   

print(y_test.shape, y_test_pred.shape)
(138241,1) (138241,)
```

Then, when I tried to simply substract them:

```py
A=y_train_pred - y_train
B=y_test_pred - y_test
```

That is the point where it crashes.

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 320. GiB for an array with shape
>   (207361, 207361) and data type float64

I find this very strange since I was using this tool with a smaller dataset without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found the issue, it was an easy one. The problem is on the shape of the arrays.

RandomForestRegressor returned the predictions as an r rows and the non-data as one of c columns. Therefore, when substracting, pandas was creating a matrix of rxc instead of a single dimension array.
The error is solved by transposing one of pairs of values.

```
A=y_train_pred - np.transpose(y_train)
B=y_test_pred - np.transpose(y_test)
```

Comment: Well, the error message was clearly reporting `array with shape (207361, 207361)`

Comment: yes it was, but I am pretty new to python, so took me a looong while to understand what it meant.